# rails new cssbundling-rails gem issue with images on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm testing the new rails *cssbundling-rails* gem. I'm following the default config, but on prod, I'm getting a 404 error with the images path in the `.scss` files

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

In development, this works properly.

```
 "scripts": {
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css  --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --outdir=app/assets/builds"
  }
```

in my **application.bootstrap.scss**

```
.table th .asc-arrow {
  background-image: url(up_arrow.gif);
}
```

I checked and my image is in the *public/assets* folder, but for some reason it doesn't have the random hash in the name when I use the `url(up_arrow.gif);` https://mywebsite.com/assets/up_arrow.gif not https://mywebsite.com/assets/up_arrow-08e7aace9abfe2ae82a1b5fb892863da155c5e30555cb8f3978ea0ccd698e5f9.gif

```
up_arrow-08e7aace9abfe2ae82a1b5fb892863da155c5e30555cb8f3978ea0ccd698e5f9.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed by https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/476, but if still not working and you want to make it simpler, try to move `up_arrow.gif` to rails public and will work.

Comment: Please show some working code. It's still very difficult to figure out via documentation what exactly the best practice is here.

Comment: The isn't a code to show. It was a bug that have been fixed